# LinearLayout (horizontal) - Swapping button positions

Tags: android

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` which has 4 image buttons in it, all the same size with the same layout params. I would like the user to be able to swap the positions of buttons 2 and 3 over. I was thinking they could perhaps swipe over the buttons to swap them, or maybe have another small button between them with an arrow image that they pressed.

My problem is I'm not sure how I would swap the button positions over in the layout! I assume I need to get hold of the index of each in the layout and then add and remove them and then cause the layout to be recalculated so it is redrawn. Is this possible?

Also it would be nice to show some animation of the buttons moving in to position but I suspect this is just not possible.

Any advice?

Comment: Here is very nice [link for drag and drop views](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+drag+and+drop+view)

Comment: Thanks but it's only available in sdk 3.0 onwards. I want to code from 1.5 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can swap your buttons:

1. You just determine their indexes (you may know them or you can iterate through all children in the layout to find the indexes of the buttons by their id's).
2. You remove one button with [`removeViewAt(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewAt%28int%29). You should use here the index which is greater in magnitude not to determine the index of second button once again in the step 3.
3. You add the removed button before another button with [`addView(View, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29). Note that the index you will use as the argument of this method is the index of the second button.
4. Call `invalidate()`.

Comment: I Got the switch working, now I'm trying to figure out if there is anyway of making the buttons animate to look like they are swapping over. It looks fairly easy to move views around during animation but I can see how I can get them to move to the exact place of another view!  Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Right I've got it working using a transformation animation. I move each button, one left and one right to the location of the other button and then listen for the end of the transformation animation. On being informed the animation has ended I replace each button in the layout :)